# FB Connect dialogs don't close

Tags: javascript, facebook

When I click on my FB log in button the FB auth dialog pops up.  After I enter my FB credentials the dialog redirects to a url like this:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?wholeBunchOfQueryParameters

or, if I was already logged into FB, the popup dialog is:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?wholeBunchOfQueryParameters

but those are blank dialogs that stay open.  Once I close the dialog the callback happens but not until then.  This is the behavior on IE and Chrome.

I did have this working fine and I think it stopped working when I got a new computer so maybe it is environmental.  I thought it has worked since then but maybe not.  I reverted to a version of my code that was working and it no longer works either so that further suggests that it is environmental but I don't know what it could be.  I could be off in the weeds.

Also, one other bit of info, I'm developing locally so I'm using localhost:port.  I did a ton of research on this issue and did see someone say to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost so I did try that as well but it didn't make a difference.

Any idea why the dialogs won't close?

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins" onlogin="afterFacebookConnect();" 
   autologoutlink="false" ></fb:login-button>
<div id="fb-root" style="display:inline; margin-left:20px;"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: 'myAppId',
        status: true, cookie: false, xfbml: true
    });
};

function afterFacebookConnect() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        alert("Hi");
        var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        if (response.authResponse) {
            window.location = "../Account/FacebookLogin?token=" +
                   access_token;
        } else {
            alert(FB.getAuthResponse);
        }
    });
};
function logout() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
        if (response.authResponse) {
            window.location = "../Account/Logout";
        } else {
            // user clicked Cancel
        }
    });    
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.getElementById('fb-root') != undefined) {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that has surfaced in the last few days (see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241915819261223).

The good news is one of FB's Engineers has just stated the following, so we should see this resolved shortly:

> We have a fix for this issue and it will be pushed soon. Stay tuned.